# Let $C$ be a space such that $C=A \cup B$ and $A \cap B ↪ A$ is a cofibration. Show that $B ↪C$ is a cofibration.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> Q. Let $C$ be a space such that $C=A \cup B$ and $A \cap B ↪ A$ is a cofibration. Show that $B ↪C$ is a cofibration.

**Attempt :** Let Y be any space. Let us denote the map $B ↪C$ by $i.$ Let $F:B \times I \to Y$ and $g:C \to Y$ be continuous maps such that $F(x,0)=(g \circ i)(x) \; \forall \; x \in B.$

Since $A \cap B ↪ A$ is a cofibration, denote it by $j$, observe that $i$ restricted to $A \cap B$ is equal to $j$. Similarly, $F$ restricted to $(A \cap B) \times I$ and $g$ restricted to $A$ are continuous maps such that $F(x,0)=(g \circ i)(x) \; \forall \; x \in A \cap B$.

Using the fact that $j$ is a cofibration, there exists a homotopy $H:A \times I \to Y$ such that $(H \circ i)=F$ and $H(x,0)=g(x) \; \forall \; x \in A$.

---

What I want to do is extend $H$ to a homotopy on $C \times I$ but I am clueless as to what information should be used to achieve this. I am looking for some hints to this end. Thank you.

Comment: Observe that if $C=A\cup B$ then it is the pushout of the inclusions $A\leftarrow A\cap B\rightarrow B$. There is a general statement about cofibrations in pushout diagrams, which you can easily prove to get the result you want (it's often called stability under base change).

Comment: @Tyrone I am unaware about pushouts. But as I see on wikipedia, for inclusions it is straightforward to get pushouts. But how will it help me to get Homotopy $H$ on $C \times I$?

Comment: If you know that $A\cap B\rightarrow A$ is a cofibration, then the map opposite it on the other side of the pushout square, namely $B\rightarrow A\cup B\cong C$, is also a cofibration. This is called "stability under base change" of cofibrations.

Comment: @Tyrone Great! Can you provide a good source to study this concept?

Comment: My first encounter with this way of thinking was in Arkowitz's "Introduction to Homotopy Theory", Chapter 3. You could also try tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology", or Strom's "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory".

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks! +1